# Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dstudioruntime2

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I installed qt creator and qt 3dstudio with the qtOnline installer for linux. I want to build a project using these two packages. I design my project in qt3dstudio and then I use qtcreator to code the logic of the program. But I cannot import qt3dstudio module into the code.any suggestions??

I need to get this going on ubuntu 16.04LTS. I couldn't find anything useful on the web about the problem. I did try to build qt3dstudio but some of the dependencies caused my ubuntu desktop to stop working and I had to reinstall ubuntu.

QT modules in my .pro file:

```
 QT += widgets qml quick gui 3dstudioruntime2
```

and when I hit build I get the following error:

```
  Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dstudioruntime2
```